# How do I sign out of hotmail email?

Tags: hotmail

I'd like to know how to sign out of hotmail email. I googled it and it said to click on my picture in top right but I don't see my picture in the top right or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the picture at top right. I'm on an awkard pc and didn't see I wasn't at top of page.